# Что от меня требует composer?

Tags: yii2, phpstorm, composer

Пытался установить фреймворк Yii2 в свой проект в IDE PhpStorm. Скачал composer, установил его, в поле Proxy Settings указал свой IP-адрес:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке выполнить данную команду **composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic** в терминале, IDE выдает следующую ошибку:

**[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url**

Как решается эта проблема?

Comment: это прокси
не пиши туда ничего
и галку убери

Comment: @DrMcSheen а как переустановить composer? просто заново запустить процесс установки?

Comment: "я не знаю что такое прокси и мне лень посмотреть об этом информацию в интернете, наверное просто введу туда свой ip-адрес")))